# Access Javascript Global Variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get javascript global variable inside jquery

HTML File

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
set_base_url(<?php echo base_url(); ?>); //base_url holds "http://www.example.com"
</script>
```

Script.JS

```
var base_url = '';
function set_base_url(url)
{
   base_url = url;
}
```

Below in Same JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#formId').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: window.base_url+'/page',
      data: some data,
      success: function(success) { //On success of map creation
        //some code
      }
    });
  });
});
```

now the problem is, base_url is empty inside document ready. If I try to access it outside using some function, it is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your scripts at the end of the body, then the ready function will be called immediately, so try revering the order of the code.  But I think you have collected some down votes because a careful use of relative URLs will do the job more cleanly.

```
<script>
set_base_url(<?php echo base_url(); ?>); //base_url holds "http://www.example.com"
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```